# String to DateTime format issue

Tags: php, laravel

I have this string **20200915173806** and I want to convert into date time format.
However I have used **date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($time));** but on localhost I am getting **2020-09-15 17:38:06** which is correct but on server I am getting **1970-01-01 05:30:00**.I am not getting the issue.

Comment: Try [DateTime::createFromFormat()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php). Then you pass in the date string and in what format it has.

Comment: Is the string *definitely* exactly the same in both environments? A 1970 date being returned implies that `strtotime` is returning false, which shouldn't ever be the case with that input.

Comment: Your method is string to time. Not sure, but may be the number casting as integer in your server. You may cast as string like, `date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime((string)$time));`

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel the preferred method is to use `Carbon` to do the job for you:

```php
$datetime = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('YmdHis','20200915173806');
```

In the code above the result will be and `Carbon`object with the time 2020-09-15 17:38:06 at UTC.

If you must have an `DateTime` You can add the following line to get one:

```php
$datetime = $datetime->toDateTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

The string is practically in the correct format already.
You just need to split it up.

```
echo substr($str, 0,4). "-". substr($str, 4,2). "-". substr($str, 6,2). " ". substr($str, 8,2). ":".substr($str, 10,2). ":" . substr($str, 12,2);
//2020-09-15 17:38:06
```